# Why isn't my textarea value centered when scrollbars are removed?

Tags: html, css, textarea

I'm trying to create a textarea that has no scroll bar and has the text centered.

I've fixed the scroll bar issue by setting the overflow style to auto or hidden. However, this causes the text to stop being centered.

The following shows my style attributes for all textareas:

```
textarea
{
    overflow:auto;
    width: 200px;
    height: 60px; 
    text-align:center;
    vertical-align:middle;   
}
```

The following shows my code for one of my textareas:

```
<textarea ID="textarea1" style="position:absolute; left:600px;">
     Bridge Crane
</textarea>
```

This is what the textareas look like right now:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears not centered because you have a bunch of whitespace inside the opening and closing tags. The content actually *is* centered when you consider the entire value. Just remove the whitespace.

```css
textarea {
    overflow: auto;
    width: 200px;
    height: 60px;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<textarea ID="textarea1">Bridge Crane</textarea>
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you want `vertical-align: middle;` because you have it inside CSS but the bad news is that we cannot do it with just `<textarea></textarea>`. We have to use a div-content-editable.

```css
div {
    overflow: auto;
    width: 200px;
    height: 60px;
    border:1px solid black; /* a border just for styling */
    text-align:center; /* text is center horizontally */
    display: table-cell; /* yes, so we can use vertical-align: middle */
    vertical-align: middle; 
}
```

```html
<div contenteditable="true">
    Row Row Row your boat
</div>
```

Comment: Do you know why vertical-align doesn't work with a text area?

Comment: @PreronaKundu because `vertical-align` doesn't work without `display:table-cell;`

Comment: I added display:table-cell; and it still won't work

Comment: Because it is an input. vertical-align is for other elements that have a specified child @PreronaKundu Like I used a `contenteditable` element in my example